# Bash: remove specific character range from specific line

Tags: awk

I have a text file and want to remove characters 23-28, ONLY from line 11:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

So the result will be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Can this be done with the sed, awk or cut command?

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always advised to mention your efforts which you have put in order to solve this problem in your post with CODE TAGS `{}` button in your post.

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` also can do this.

```
sed -E '11 s/^(.{22}).{6}(.*)/\1\2/' file
```

On line 11 (exactly), remember the the first 22 chars, ignore the next 6, remember the rest of the line. Replace the line with the remembered parts.

Everywhere else, just print as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(since samples are not provided so couldn't test it). Also I have assumed that you need to perform this actio from 11th line onwards to till last line of Input_file.

```
awk 'FNR>10{print substr($0,1,22) substr($0,29);next} 1'   Input_file
```

In case you want to remove characters from 23 to 28 in 11th line NOT all lines then try following.

```
awk 'FNR==11{print substr($0,1,22) substr($0,29);next} 1'   Input_file
```

Comment: OP said line 11, not every line after 10.

Comment: @EdMorton, I read like `from line 11` in post Ed sir so I have done the same.

Comment: I read it as `I want to remove X from line 11`. Guess we'll see what the OP posts when she gets around to providing sample input/output.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove specifically from line 11.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==11{$0=substr($0,1,22) substr($0,29)} 1' file
```